# How to add data to email sent by flow

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I have created in Microsoft Forms a form. Once submit the form is clicked it puts new entry into Excel file saved in SharePoint.
Then I created flow: when new answer submitted send email to.
It works fine. It notifies me that there is new answer.
Next step that I stuck at is getting those answers displayed in the emails body, so I don't have to go to file saved in SharePoint to check them.

Can please somebody help with this?
Thanks

Comment: Which flow trigger are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "When a new response is submitted" trigger to run the flow on new response submission for your form created using Microsoft Forms.

Then you have to use the "Get response details" action to get the user responses/answers which you can use to send in email.

**Example**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Source**: [Send an email when there's a new form response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/forms/popular-scenarios#send-an-email-when-theres-a-new-form-response)

---

There is a ready to use Power automate flow template as well for such requirements. You can use this template to get started with and then customize it as per your requirements.

**Template**: [Send an email to responder when response submitted in Microsoft Forms](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/19f79910d8da440981811b9f8e43ffcc/send-an-email-to-responder-when-response-submitted-in-microsoft-forms/)